# On Databrick in notebooks jsonschema is reported missing for spacy, but it is installed

Tags: databricks, spacy, jsonschema

On Databricks on Azure in a Notebook that apparently has loaded Spacy successfully.

The following code errors when using the Matcher iterating over documents passed to it. The **jsonschema** is stated as being missing however when checking, the json schema **is installed** and was also installed using

```
%sh
pip install jsonschema
```

and later to make it version specific

```
%sh
pip install 'jsonschema>=2.6.0,<3.1.0'
```

Both sucessfully installed.

Here is the error message :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------  
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)  
<command-3008938145872993> in <module>  

---> 12     ALL_DATA_tmp     = [parse_train_data_sorted(d) for d in nlp.pipe(text_tmp_ls) ]  
     13     ALL_DATA = ALL_DATA  + ALL_DATA_tmp  
     14     print(f'length ALL_DATA : {len(ALL_DATA)}')    

<command-3008938145872993> in <listcomp>(.0)  
     10     #ALL_DATA_tmp     = [parse_train_data(d) for d in  
 nlp.pipe(text_tmp_ls) ]  
     11   
---> 12     ALL_DATA_tmp     = [parse_train_data_sorted(d) for d in  nlp.pipe(text_tmp_ls) ]    
     13     ALL_DATA = ALL_DATA  + ALL_DATA_tmp    
     14     print(f'length ALL_DATA : {len(ALL_DATA)}')    
  
<command-3008938145872990> in parse_train_data_sorted(doc)  
     27     prev_end = -1    
     28   
---> 29     detections_unsorted = iterate_matchers(doc)  
     30   
     31     detections_sorted = sorted(detections_unsorted, key=lambda element:    (element[1], element[2]))  

<command-3008938145872990> in iterate_matchers(doc)  
      5     '''  
      6     detections = []  
----> 7     matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab, validate=True)  
      8     matcher.add("STANDARDS_9239",  None, *create_patterns_9239())  
      9     detections = detections + [(doc[start:end].start_char,   doc[start:end].end_char, 'STANDARD_9239') for idx, start, end in matcher(doc)]  

matcher.pyx in spacy.matcher.matcher.Matcher.__init__()    

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py in get_json_validator(schema)  
    744     # TODO: replace with (stable) Draft6Validator, if available  
    745     if jsonschema is None:  
--> 746         raise ValueError(Errors.E136)  
    747     return jsonschema.Draft4Validator(schema)  
    748 

ValueError: [E136] This additional feature requires the jsonschema library to be  
 installed:  
pip install jsonschema
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem thus :

1. Define Spacy library in Databricks, ensure automatic install is not selected

The blue spacy link should direct to the following : https://pypi.org/project/spacy/

2. Start a version 7 , ML cluster. Once started.

Navigate to the library and manually select and click install on the Cluster.

3. Now open notebook and run cell,

   %sh

   pip install 'jsonschema>=2.6.0,<3.1.0'
4. In next cell run

   %sh

   python -m spacy validate

This confirms Spacy exists on cluster but no models

5. In next cell install the model

   %sh

   python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
6. Validate model now exists.

   %sh

   python -m spacy validate
7. In next cell run the following imports python code

   import spacy

   import json

8 . In next cell run and load ( in my case )the middle size English model , you may be loading and running a different sized model and language for your application. See Spacy website for exact name.

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
```

9 .Finally the code that was failing now works.

Later on the code that previous errored now works.

```
row_step =20
ALL_DATA = []
for i  in  range (0,df.shape[0] , row_step) :

    start_pos = i 
    end_pos   = i  + row_step  
    print(f'{start_pos}   {end_pos}')
    text_tmp_ls   = df.iloc[start_pos:end_pos]['text'].to_list()

    ALL_DATA_tmp     = [parse_train_data_sorted(d) for d in nlp.pipe(text_tmp_ls) ]
    ALL_DATA = ALL_DATA  + ALL_DATA_tmp
    print(f'length ALL_DATA : {len(ALL_DATA)}')
```

Now Spacy is stepping through a list of texts , and processing subsets of the list 20 items at a time using using the Matcher to find entities. This avoids memory breaches a handy technique..

I believe that all shell pip commands should run before any python imports that may depend on them.